# How to detect Ellipses on a real image

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, object-detection, detection, ellipse

I'm trying to recognise the midfield ellipse of a football pitch. I've tried different solutions found online like Hough Transform and Template matching, but unfortunately I wasn't able to make them works.
Images are taken from a real football match, so there are different camera shots and orientations.

At the moment I obtained the best result filtering out pixels outside the pitch (using a **color mask**) and using some transformations like **Gaussian Blur, Canny**, and techniques like **Edge contouring, and [fitEllipse() from openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa)**.

The starting image after the mask:
[image]

Canny image:
[image]

Here I performed Edge contouring and filtered out not relevant edges using aspect_ratio:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

min_aspect_ratio = 3  # Minimum aspect ratio threshold (adjust as needed)
max_aspect_ratio = 50  # Maximum aspect ratio threshold (adjust as needed)

# Create a copy of the original image to draw bounding rectangles
image_with_rectangles = image.copy()

# Iterate through the contours
for contour in contours:
    # Calculate the aspect ratio of the bounding rectangle
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    aspect_ratio = float(w) / h

    # Check if the aspect ratio falls within the specified range
    if min_aspect_ratio < aspect_ratio < max_aspect_ratio:
        # Draw a green bounding rectangle around the contour
        cv2.rectangle(image_with_rectangles, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 0), 2)

# Display the image with the bounding rectangles
print("Image with Bounding Rectangles")
cv2_imshow(image_with_rectangles)

filtered_contours = [
    cnt for cnt in contours
    if min_aspect_ratio < (float(cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[2]) / cv2.boundingRect(cnt)[3]) < max_aspect_ratio
]

result_image = np.zeros_like(original_image)  # Create a blank canvas

cv2.drawContours(result_image, filtered_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Draw the filtered contours in green

# Display or save the result_image as needed
cv2_imshow(result_image)
```

Image with bounding rectangles:
[image]

Image with contours:
[image]

The final step consist of trying to fit an ellipse, I encountered a lot of problems to make cv2.fitEllipse() works, here my solution:

```
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(result_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2_imshow(gray_image)

# find the contours
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_image, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print("\nNumber of contours detected:", len(contours))

ellipse_image = original_image.copy()
ellipses = []
orientations = []

for c in filtered_contours:

  #if it contains at least 5 points (higher the value lower the number of ellipses)
  if len(c) >= 10:
    print(len(c))

    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(c)

    # Get the major and minor axes of the ellipse
    major_axis, minor_axis = ellipse[1]
    # Calculate the aspect ratio of the ellipse
    aspect_ratio = major_axis / minor_axis
    #we want a high aspect ratio, meaning that is much wider then taller
    if 0.1 <= aspect_ratio <= 0.2:
      print("\nRatio: ", aspect_ratio)
      print("M and m axes: ", major_axis, minor_axis)

      if major_axis < minor_axis:
        ellipses.append(ellipse)
        orientations.append(int(ellipse[2]))

for e in ellipses:
   cv2.ellipse(ellipse_image, e, (255, 255, 0), 2)


print("\nMiddlefield contour:")
cv2_imshow(ellipse_image)
```

Final result:
[image]

How to keep only one ellipse (the correct one)?

### EDIT AFTER VITOR'S POST

It's very important to apply a lot of image pre-processing operations to clean much more contours detected on input images. If you can get a good and clean shape of the midfield ellipse, his algorithm can be applied to detect and keep only one ellipse.
Results has some false positives but applying some range restriction on area, aspect-ratio and length of the ellipses, I got good ones.

Below some examples. As you can see it depends on the filtered contours.

Good result:
[image: Contours]
[image: Ellipse detected]

Not so bad result:
[image: Contours]
[image: Ellipse]

Bad result (ellipse not detected):
[image: Contours]
[image: Ellipse]

Comment: *do not* attempt to detect ellipses. XY problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you add details?

Comment: you ought to explain what you need this for, what's the goal, _why_ do you need that area...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want to highlight the midfield area because I want to recognise the areas (if I'm left or right side) and understand who is attacking for example, for some statistics. I don't need a perfect ellipse, but I need one close to, for a demo to show to my professor.

Comment: @toyotaSupra because there aren't complete ellipses on the image I guess, because of the straight line in the middle and players. But I thought that methods like fitEllipse() would find it even in case of noises.

Comment: so it's not about that ellipse, it's about finding a relationship between the camera view and a model of the soccer field. that's not splitting hairs. that allows you to understand the problem in ways that actually lead somewhere. commercial solutions are a lot more complex, also assume that the camera has a fixed position and only pans/tilts/zooms. you could try feature matching here, without such assumptions. match the view against a model of the field. it's got to *look* reasonably realistic for features to be similar.

Answer (score 1):

What i did was closing the ellipse with morphology operators. And selecting the biggest ellipse (which has the biggest area).

- Importing libraries and reading the image in GRAYSCALE

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('K8hNf.png',0)
```

- The morphology operation

```py
kernel_square = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(50,50))
img = cv.morphologyEx(img,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel_square,iterations=1)
```

- Find the Countours and also change the image from gray to RGB so we can plot the ellipse in green.

```py
contours, _ = cv.findContours(img, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

- The following algorithm finds the max area ellipse. It's simple. You can also utilize `cv2.contourArea`.

```py
largest_ellipse = None
max_area = 0

for contour in contours:
    if len(contour) >= 5:
        ellipse = cv.fitEllipse(contour)
        area = ellipse[1][0] * ellipse[1][1] * np.pi # Calculate the area of the fitted ellipse
        if area > max_area:
            max_area = area
            largest_ellipse = ellipse


if largest_ellipse is not None:
    cv.ellipse(img, largest_ellipse, (0,255,0),2)
else:
    print('No ellipses found')


plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
```

[image: results]

By removing the unwanted lines on top of the image and also remove the players skeletons you may improve the fitting of the ellipse.

The fitting may never be perfect because of the camera angle distortion.

Comment: it works only with frames where the ellipse is clearly visible and it's not touched by other lines (like the vertical midfield lines, sometimes it remains). Also I need something to discard frames where there isn't the midfield area, otherwise detects ellipses everywhere

Comment: Update: as I said to use this method you need to apply a lot of image pre-processing to keep only a good ellipse shape contour. After some test with much more cleaned images I can say that this algorithm can be applied and you can get good results, still it's very important have clean contours and adjust some geometrical parameters like area, aspect-ratio and length of the ellipses, otherwise you can get a lot of false positives.